# what are the best practices/strategies to handle session timeout in MOSS2007?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, session-timeout

I have a MOSS2007 web application (created using publishing site template). In this app, user is allowed to add various items of interest. Those item of interest are saved in DB as a group. Thus each user has more than one group of interests. User is allowed to add/delete/edit interests within a group at will.

My queries are as follows

- How to handle cases when user adds items of interest and never saves it in a group before MOSS2007 session times out?
- How to handle cases when user adds items of interest, saves it and then adds more before MOSS2007 session times out.
- How to handle cases when user adds items of interest, saves it, delete some items from saved ones before MOSS2007 session times out.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

> How to handle cases when user adds
>   items of interest and never saves it
>   in a group before MOSS2007 session
>   times out?

Items are either stored in a local cookie, so they are there when the user logs in to MOSS again, or are lost.

> How to handle cases when user adds
>   items of interest, saves it and then
>   adds more before MOSS2007 session
>   times out.

New items are either saved in cookie, or lost.

> How to handle cases when user adds
>   items of interest, saves it, delete
>   some items from saved ones before
>   MOSS2007 session times out.

The deletion method should delete the records from the database. So they would be synced already. If however, you need a rollback option, you could do something similar to the Recycle bin functionality in MOSS...

Hope that helps.